# How to regex string that can end with a number and group each part

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following test strings:

```
Battery Bank 1
Dummy 32 Segment 12
System
Modbus 192.168.0.1 Group
```

I need a regex that can match and group these as follows:

```
Group 1: Battery Bank
Group 2: 1

Group 1: Dummy 32 Segment
Group 2: 12

Group 1: System
Group 2: null

Group 1: Modbus 192.168.0.1 Group
Group 2: null
```

Basically, capture everything (including numbers) into group 1 unless the string ends with a whitespace followed by 1 or more digits. If it does, capture this number into group 2.

This regex is not doing what I need as everything is captured into the first group.

```
([\w ]+)( \d+)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/GEtb5G/1/

Comment: Like this? `(.+?)(\d+|$)$` https://regex101.com/r/q3cOXJ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically, capture everything (including numbers) into group 1 unless the string ends with a whitespace followed by 1 or more digits. If it does, capture this number into group 2.

You may use this group that allows an empty match in 2nd capture group:

```sh
^(.+?) *(\d+|)$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEtb5G/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.+?)`: Match 1+ of any character (lazy) in capture group #1
- `*`: Match 0 or more spaces
- `(\d+|)`: Match 1+ digits or nothing in 2nd capture group
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
^\s*(.*[^\d\s])(?:\s*(\d+))?\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FCZzwl/2) (note `\s` are replaced with spaces since the test string in the demo is a single multiline string).

If the regex is to be used with a multiline flag to match *lines* in a longer multiline text, you can use

```js
^[^\S\r\n]*(.*[^\d\s])(?:[^\S\r\n]*(\d+))?[^\S\r\n]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FCZzwl/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*[^\d\s])`  - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a char other than a digit and whitespace
- `(?:\s*(\d+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

In the second regex, `[^\S\r\n]*` matches any zero or more whitespaces other than LF and CR chars.